# Can't update table

Tags: mysql, sql, tsqlt

So right now I have a simple SQL store procedure which I can call to update one of the tables in my database. Within the store procedure, I have an If conditional statement:

```
IF 1 > 0 THEN   
         UPDATE TABLE_A 
         SET COLUMN_1 =299999 
         WHERE COLUMN_2 ='2014-01-03'  and COLUMN_3=0;
```

I'm pretty sure the update clause has no problem because when I run it separately, it updates the table fine. I can see the value being updated in the table.

However, right when I put it after the `IF` statement(like the code above), the update fails(returns me no rows affected).

I'm pretty sure the IF statement is correct as well(right now I put it as 1>0 just for testing).

If I put an insert statement after the IF, it works fine too. A new row is being inserted into the table. This is so weird. Any help ?

Comment: What does `SELECT * FROM TABLE_A WHERE COLUMN_2 ='2014-01-03'  and COLUMN_3=0;` return?

Comment: hi, it returns me the correct row

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's T-SQL try using a `BEGIN` statement instead of then

```
IF 1 > 0
BEGIN
UPDATE TABLE_A 
SET COLUMN_1 =299999 
WHERE COLUMN_2 ='2014-01-03'  and COLUMN_3=0
END
```

Comment: Thx guys, I figured out where the problem is. I accidentally named one of my input parameter as the same name as one of my column names, so I think it messed up the update part.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
     UPDATE TABLE_A 
     SET COLUMN_1 =299999 
     WHERE COLUMN_2 ='2014-01-03'  
     AND COLUMN_3=0
     AND 1 > 0 ;              <------- put it in where clause
```

Comment: well, thx for your answer, but I really need the IF statement because I need to do something else using ELSEIF and ELSE after that